# Joining cluster takes forever

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have set up my master node and I am trying to join a worker node as follows:

```
kubeadm join 192.168.30.1:6443 --token 3czfua.os565d6l3ggpagw7 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:3a94ce61080c71d319dbfe3ce69b555027bfe20f4dbe21a9779fd902421b1a63
```

However the command hangs forever in the following state:

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
```

Since this is just a warning, why does it actually fails?

**edit**: I noticed the following in my `/var/log/syslog`

```
Mar 29 15:03:15 ubuntu-xenial kubelet[9626]: F0329 15:03:15.353432    9626 server.go:193] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory
Mar 29 15:03:15 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Mar 29 15:03:15 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had to do with `kubeadm` not installing a networking CNI-compatible solution out of the box;

Therefore, without this step the `kubernetes` nodes/master are unable to establish any form of communication;

The following task addressed the issue:

```
- name: kubernetes.yml --> Install Flannel
  shell: kubectl -n kube-system apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
  become: yes
  environment:
    KUBECONFIG: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
  when: inventory_hostname in (groups['masters'] | last)
```

Comment: when: with run_once better than last

Answer (score 9):

First if you want to see more detail when your worker joins to the master use:

```
kubeadm join 192.168.1.100:6443 --token m3jfbb.wq5m3pt0qo5g3bt9     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:d075e5cc111ffd1b97510df9c517c122f1c7edf86b62909446042cc348ef1e0b --v=2
```

Using the above command I could see that my worker could not established connection with the master, so i just stoped the firewall:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved by creating a new token
using this command:

> `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`

and use the token generated for joining other nodes to the cluster

Answer (score 0):

I did get the same error on CentOS 7 but in my case join command worked without problems, so it was indeed just a warning.

```
>  [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker
> cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the
> guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/ [preflight] Reading
> configuration from the cluster... [preflight] FYI: You can look at
> this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config
> -oyaml' [kubelet-start] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.14" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace
```

As the official documentation mentions, there are two common issues that make the init hang (I guess it also applies to join command):

> the default cgroup driver configuration for the kubelet differs from
>   that used by Docker. Check the system log file (e.g. /var/log/message)
>   or examine the output from journalctl -u kubelet. If you see something
>   like the following:

First try the steps from [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#kubeadm-blocks-waiting-for-control-plane-during-installation) and if that does not work please provide more information so we can troubleshoot further if needed.

Comment: It seems this issue is related to the CRI configuration on master; I have no problem creating the cluster; the `join` command is the one that fails; however I have installed `docker` using the exact same way in master and nodes.

Comment: I posted results of join command, so it works in my case even with this warning. Is this a clear cluster I mean can you just reset it? If yes try to do `kubeadm reset` and reinstall docker from official documentation site (have you also tried [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/#docker))?

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of k8s deployment scripts that broke recently with this same error message... it looks like docker changed it's install.  Try this --

previous install:
apt-get isntall docker-ce

updated install:
apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

Answer (score 0):

#### How /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml is created?

Regarding the `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory` error.

Below are steps that should occur on the worker node in order for the mentioned file to be created.

1 ) The creation of the `/var/lib/kubelet/` folder. 
It is created when the kubelet service is installed as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

2 ) The creation of `config.yaml`. 
 The kubeadm join flow should take place so when you run `kubeadm join`, kubeadm uses the Bootstrap Token credential to perform a TLS bootstrap, which fetches the credential needed to download the `kubelet-config-1.X` ConfigMap and writes it to `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`.

After a successful execution you should see the logs below:

```
.
.
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
.
.
```

So, after these 2 steps you should have `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` in place.

#### Failure of the kubeadm join flow

In your case, it seems that the [kubeadm join flow](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/#join-workflow) failed which might happen due to multiple reasons like bad configuration of iptables, ports that are already in use, container runtime not installed properly, etc' - as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/).

As far as I know, the fact that no networking CNI-compatible solution was in place should not affect the creation of `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`:

A) We can see the under the [kubeadm preflight checks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/implementation-details/#preflight-checks) what issues will cause the join phase to fail.

B ) I also tested this issue by removing the current solution I used (Calico) and ran `kubeadm reset` and `kubeadm join` again and no errors appeared in the `kubeadm` logs (I've got the successful execution logs I mentioned above) and `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` was created properly.

(*) Of course that the cluster can't function in this state - I just wanted to emphasize that I think the problem was one of the options mentioned in A.